# Preventing code duplication in Django

Tags: python, django

I have these 2 functions that are almost the same:

```
def handle_keywords(self, scan_id):
    keywords = Keyword.objects.all()
    for kwrd in keywords:
        self.process_rss_url(kwrd.rss, SourceType.GOOGLE_ALERTS, kwrd.id, kwrd.last_scan_time, scan_id)
        kwrd.last_scan_time = timezone.now()
        kwrd.save()

def handle_rss(self, scan_id):
    all_rss = RSS.objects.all()
    for rss in all_rss:
        self.process_rss_url(rss.feed_url, SourceType.RSS, rss.id, rss.last_scan_time, scan_id)
        rss.last_scan_time = timezone.now()
        rss.save()
```

What is a good way to reduce the code duplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def generate_func(url_attr, type_class, source_type):
    def f(self, scan_id):
        for keyword in type_class.objects.all():
            self.process_rss_url(getattr(keyword, url_attr), source_type, keyword.id, keyword.last_scan_time, scan_id)
            keyword.last_scan_time = timezone.now()
            keyword.save()

    return f

handle_keywords = generate_func('rss', Keyword, SourceType.GOOGLE_ALERTS)
handle_rss = generate_func('feed_url', RSS, SourceType.RSS)
```

Comment: The "keywords" temp is unnecessary. I think `SourceType.RSS` and `SourceType.GOOGLE_ALERTS` are constants, but it's not certain from the code given.

Comment: @Snowbody Thanks for pointing out about `keywords`. Why does it matter if those are constants?

Comment: Because then they can be passed in and used directly, saving a call to  `getattr()`

Comment: @Snowbody That's what I was wondering. I'll change that.